# How to cluster points based on both x and y value ranges in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, cluster-computing

I have dataset of RNA expression values of different samples. I applied linear fitting and Bayes statistics on them and then plotted log fold change ("LogFC") against "P.Value" to obtain the following ggplot. Now I want to colour values with "LogFC" < -2 or > 2 and values with "P.Value" <0.05 both with a different colour than the rest of values. How can I do that?

[image: ggplot volcano plot of logFc and P value of expressed genes]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you could indeed plot subsets of the data as layers, you could also make the colour aesthetic a nested `ifelse()` statement. You'll get the correct legend too. Example below:

```r
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(0)

df <- data.frame(
  logFC = rt(10000, 10),
  pvalue = runif(10000)
)

ggplot(df, aes(logFC, log10(pvalue))) +
  geom_point(
    aes(colour = ifelse(is.na(pvalue) | pvalue > 0.05 | abs(logFC) < 2, "n.s.",
                        ifelse(logFC >= 2, "Up", "Down")))
  ) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("limegreen", "grey50", "dodgerblue"),
                      name = "Category") +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "reverse")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-09-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Seems you used a `geom_point`-plot for your whole dataset.
One way to solve your question is to add additional point-layers with subsets.

You didn't provide an example dataset yet, so I used the iris dataset.
I recolored smaller and higher values of Sepal.Length by subseting the dataset and added points in blue. Futhermore small values in Sepal.Width got the color green.

To transfer this code to your case. Filter your dataset for your desired `LogFC` and/or `P.Value` and add these datasets and a color argument to additional `geom_point`layers.

```
ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point(color = "red") +
  geom_point(data = iris[iris$Sepal.Length < 5 | iris$Sepal.Length > 7, ], color = "blue") +
  geom_point(data = iris[iris$Sepal.Width < 3, ], color = "green")
```

[image]